# Prove: $\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2+1} =0$ on the annulus $6\lt |z| \lt 8$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, solution-verification

Let $D$ be the annulus $6\lt |z| \lt 8$ and let $C$ be any simple closed contour inside $D$. Show that there holds:
$$\int_C \frac{dz}{z^2+1} =0$$

---

This has two singular points, $z=\pm i$, these are both outside of the annulus and hence by Cauchy Goursat theorem, we know that when $C$ is a simple closed contour in $\Bbb C$ and where this is analytic in and on any contour within $D$, and hence the integral on any contour in $D$ evaluates to $0$

Is that all I need?

Comment: Your argument can also show that $\int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 0$ for any such $C$.

Comment: The theorem you are quoting holds only on simply connected domains, whereas the annulus is not simply connected.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Any contour within this is though

Comment: For your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Sorry, I miswrote(but correctly read) the word 'simple' in the question, was that the problem?

Comment: @John See typo correction is that better?

Comment: The problem is spotted by Amital Yuval. You **needed** to have simply connected domain in order to use the theorem.

Comment: You have to analyse the poles and see that the integral around each of them cancels out. Then you will know that a path that goes _around_ the annulus still has zero integral.

Comment: @Arthur Ahh that was the path I didn't consider for some reason, thanks! So just Residue calculations