# Contour Integration of Simple Closed Contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let C be any simple closed contour inside the annulus 4 < |z| < 6. Show that there holds:

$$ \int_C \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = 0$$

To begin:
I know that there are poles at $\pm i$ and that the integral can be rewritten as

$$ \int_C \frac{dz}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$

I think there is a theorem on multiply connected domains that I need to understand, but am unsure as to how one would approach this question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324680/prove-int-c-fracdzz21-0-on-the-annulus-6-lt-z-lt-8

Answer (score 1):

Either both poles or neither are inside the contour.  The residues at the poles are ....  Apply the Residue Theorem.

Comment: Since the poles are not within the annulus, can I say that their residues equate to zero?

Comment: No, the residues are not $0$.  The definition of residue has nothing to do with the annulus.

Comment: Right. So is it only when the poles lie outside of the contour do we disregard them when using the Residue Theorem?

Comment: That is correct.